# Beego: orm Read() vs orm RelatedSel()

Tags: database, go, orm, beego

Supposing I have the following structs defined:

```
type User struct {
Id       int       `orm:"pk;auto"
Username string    `orm:"size(64);unique"`
Email    string    `orm:"size(255);unique"`
Password string    `orm:"size(64)"`
Profile  *Profile  `orm:"rel(one);on_delete(cascade)"`
}

type Profile struct {
Id          int    `orm:"pk;auto"`
User        *User  `orm:"reverse(one)"`
Description string `orm:"size(255)"`
}
```

How much can my application be affected in terms of performance if I do a cascaded query directly when I just need the info present in the first struct (User.Id, User.Password, User.Email, or User.Username)?

Basically do:

```
o := orm.NewOrm()

user := &User{}
err := o.QueryTable("user").Filter("Username", username).RelatedSel().One(user)
```

Instead of

```
o := orm.NewOrm()

user := &User{Username: username}
err := o.Read(user, "username")
```